# Entity Framework Combobox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Диаграмма БД

[image]

Создал приложение, которое позволяет редактировать таблицу User при помощи Datagrid и сохранять результат.

MainWindow.xaml

```
        <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="typeViewSource"
                              d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Type}, CreateList=True}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="userViewSource"
                              d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:User}, CreateList=True}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource userViewSource}" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Type" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Тип" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource typeViewSource}}"
                                SelectedValue="ID"
                                SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=ID_Type}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Save" Click="Save_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private TESTEntities _testEntitiesCnt;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _testEntitiesCnt = new TESTEntities();
            var typeViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource) (FindResource("typeViewSource")));
            _testEntitiesCnt.Type.Load();
            typeViewSource.Source = _testEntitiesCnt.Type.Local;
            var usersViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource) (FindResource("userViewSource")));
            _testEntitiesCnt.User.Load();
            usersViewSource.Source = _testEntitiesCnt.User.Local;
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _testEntitiesCnt.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _testEntitiesCnt.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при выборе значения в колонке "тип" меняются выбранные значение во всех combobox, а не только в одном. Как можно привязать к колонке выпадающий список из которого можно было бы выбрать тип для каждого пользователя?

Comment: 1 http://hashcode.ru/questions/298651/c-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-combobox-%D0%B2-wpf-datagrid-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=298668#298668
2 http://hashcode.ru/questions/297488/c-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-datagridview?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=297654#297654

Comment: Я уже видел эти вопросы, но у меня не получается сделать так, что бы в каждом combobox был выбрана текущий тип для каждого пользователя

Comment: @Stepan Kurennyh, в приведённом коде я даже попыток не виду. У вас нет колонки с комбобоксом. Напишите, как Вы делаете, и, думаю, сможем найти ошибку, из-за которой оно не работает.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного напутали с связыванием значения:

```
<ComboBox
  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource typeViewSource}}"
  SelectedValue="ID"
  SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=ID_Type}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

К сожалению, запутался - не представлены Ваши сущности User и Type. Предположу, что они выглядят так:

```
public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int TypeId { get; set; }
            public string Fio { get; set; }
        }
        public class Type
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

А теперь исправляем разметку datagrid - я бы предложил использовать DataGridComboBoxColumn, вместо DataGridTemplateColumn. В этом случае будет так:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource typeViewSource}}"
DisplayMemberPath="Description"
SelectedValuePath="Id"
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TypeId}"
></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

ItemsSource - ссылка на ваш источник данных. это может быть и просто связываемая коллекция, а можно заполнить это свойство и из codebehind, если указано имя колонки.

DisplayMemberPath - строковое значение. указывает свойство сущности Type, которое должен отображать комбобокс.

SelectedValuePath - строковое значение. указывает свойство сущности Type, из которого будет извлекаться значения для связывания с родительской сущностью User.

SelectedValueBinding- связывание поля User.TypeId с полем Type.Id сущности, выбранной из списка.

Теперь, если у Вас в поле TypeId имеются значения, они свяжутся с нужным элементом списка самостоятельно.

Чтиво: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/gg983481.aspx

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!